Does git push --force push only committed changes?
What does git push --force origin master actually do? Does it clobber origin/master with only the files committed in the local repo, or does it clobber origin/master with everything in the local repo, even stuff that was never git added and git commited in the local repo?

Part of the misunderstanding comes from the idea that git pushes files. It does not. Git pushes only commits (and sometimes tags when you ask for it).

The command git push --force forces the update of the remote's ref even when this is not an ancestor of the local ref.

Usually, the command refuses to update a remote ref that is not an ancestor of the local ref used to overwrite it.

In Git, a ref can only point to a commit. So, the only changes that are pushed with git push --force are the ones that have been committed. Uncommitted changes are never pushed to the remote.
